# Unexpected huge delay on homepage loading in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, delay, minify, pagespeed

I have my wordpress site without any big plugin, very light, except for a theme that adds some external js. I'm experiencing a delay of 8525ms on the loading of the main document, as you can see from the attachment:

[image]

As you can see also here in the details it's just this homepage which requests these 8 seconds to load: [image]

I tried compressing the site, minifying all the script, disabling the json api and some other tricks but still that page will take 8525ms to load. Why? Any tricks? Even assuming that some scripts require some seconds to load it is normal to have all that time for a simple page with 20 super compressed pics with a scroll script and a gradient background?

Comment: 1) Do you have the same behaviour when you test it locally?
2) Try and put die() in different sections to see where the actual issue is.

Can you give us some more details regarding which Theme you are using and which Wordpress version. 

Also details about the hosting are also required.

Comment: Locally it works with a normal decent speed. No delay. 
The theme is "themify ultra"
Wordpress version is the latest (4.7.2)
Hosting is Netsons, with cpanel and database updated to the latests.

Comment: Do you have access to the error log of the hosting? 
Also do you know how much memory you have assigned or available. 

Since these settings might be the reason why it's slow online and not offline.

The lowest plan available on Netsons is only 'I/O 1024 KB/s' which might be a bottleneck if your Wordpress install is bigger than 1Mb which it probably is.

RAM looks to be 1GB ? Should be fine. Depends how much the PHP Max Memory Setting is, if you can figure that out that would also be helpfull. My guess is you need better hosting.

Comment: No, I don't have access to the error log since I have the base plane. 
I'm trying to figure out all the rest and considering upgrading to another hosting. So you think all this delay could be just the memory limit of my plan? 
Thank you for now ;)

Comment: Solved as described in my answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Following your prompt answers I figured out that the problem was the memory limit for the php so I solved doing this:

1. Adding this string `@ini_set( 'memory_limit', apply_filters( 'admin_memory_limit', '2048M' ) );` to the line 69 of my admin.php file.
2. Adding `<?php define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); ?>`to the wp-config.php

Now all my homepage loads in 700ms even if my provider still remains a little decadent italian one, but decent.

Answer (score 0):

Your delay is happening before any scripts are loaded, and the JSON api shouldn't affect the loading of the main site unless you are calling it from within the PHP code itself. The slowdown you are seeing is in PHP, not in the browser. It might be a problem in the php side of the theme, or it might be an issue with your server or the database.

Comment: Since the slowdown happens only on server and not locally this would mean that the php is all right and the problem would be in the server\database side, as you mentioned. Any ways to go further to detect the problem?

Comment: PHP is running on the server, so it could be the PHP. Check logs, especially anything pertaining to rendering time and query time

Comment: Thank you. Solved as described in my answer.